# python find lru_cache alternative that would work with multiprocessing

Tags: python, caching, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a lru_cache alterative to get data from a sqlite database using queries in multiple processes

here a simple reproducible example:

```
import sqlite3
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


db = sqlite3.connect('db')
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
data.to_sql('data', db, index = True, if_exists = 'replace')

def get_multi_data(queue_):
    for i in range(100):
        get_data(i%10, queue_)

def get_data(row, queue_):
    q = f'select * from data where `index` = {row}'
    data = pd.read_sql(q, db)
    print(data)
    queue_.put(data)

processes = []
queue_ = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

for i in range(10):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target = get_multi_data, args = (queue_, ))
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)
    
for process in processes:
    try:
        process.join()
    except KeyboardInterupt:
        process.terminate()
        process.join()
```

I would like to use a decorator on the `get_data` function , similar to the builtin `functools.lru_cache` but that would work with multiprocessing.

I have looked around a found that [pymemcache](https://pypi.org/project/pymemcache/) could work as a cache for such matter; I expected that [ring](https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) could already have a nicely done decorator.

With memcache and ring i adjust the code as follow:

```
import ring
import requests
import pymemcache.client

client = pymemcache.client.Client(('127.0.0.1', 11211))

@ring.memcache(client, expire=60)
def get_data(row, queue_):
    q = f'select * from data where `index` = {row}'
    data = pd.read_sql(q, db)
    print(data)
    queue_.put(data)
```

I receive the error `Connection refused`. I am not knowledgeable enough with python to orient myself from then on.. If anyone knows how to write a lru decorator function that i could use with multiprocesing, or explain me why the `ring` solution is not working, it would be amazing.

---

EDIT: full error message:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wirerope/rope.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self._wire(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymemcache/client/base.py", line 1018, in _fetch_cmd
    self._connect()
  File "<ipython-input-15-233a44ad5a8e>", line 19, in get_multi_data
    get_data(i%10, queue_)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ring/func/sync.py", line 45, in get_or_update
    result = wire.storage.get(key)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymemcache/client/base.py", line 420, in _connect
    sock.connect(sockaddr)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ring/func/base.py", line 798, in __call__
    return self.run(self._rope.config.default_action, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ring/func/base.py", line 1040, in get
    value = self.get_value(key)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wirerope/rope.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self._wire(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vincent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ring/func/sync.py", line 306, in get_value
    value = self.backend.get(key)
```

Comment: Is "Connection refused" the complete error? If not, show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher edited